# Object::cast_to in godot still casts even when the cast is invalid

Tags: c++, godot

I have a class for a projectile defined like this:

```
namespace godot
{

class Projectile : public RigidBody2D
{
    // Godot structure
private:
    GDCLASS(Projectile, RigidBody2D);

public:
    virtual void _physics_process(double delta) override;

    Projectile();
    ~Projectile();

};
}
```

Then I have a class for anything that can be shot:

```
class ShootableObject : public RigidBody2D
{
    // Godot structure
private:
    GDCLASS(ShootableObject, RigidBody2D);

public:
    virtual bool receiveDamage(double damage);
    
    ShootableObject();
    ~ShootableObject();

};
```

This is how I register them with the engine:

```
#include "Projectile.h"
#include "ShootableObject.h"

void initialize_example_module(godot::ModuleInitializationLevel p_level)
{
    if (p_level != godot::MODULE_INITIALIZATION_LEVEL_SCENE)
    {
        return;
    }
    godot::ClassDB::register_class<godot::Projectile>();
    godot::ClassDB::register_class<godot::ShootableObject>();
}
```

Then for collisions, I do this in the projectile class:

```
void Projectile::_physics_process(double delta)
{
  TypedArray<Node2D> colliders = get_colliding_bodies();
  bool hit = false;
  for (int i=0; i<colliders.size(); ++i)
  {
    Object* o = colliders[i];

    if (PhysicsBody2D* body = Object::cast_to<PhysicsBody2D>(o))
    {
      if (ShootableObject* shootable = Object::cast_to<ShootableObject>(body))
      {
        if(shootable->is_inside_tree())
          shootable->receiveDamage(props.damage);
      }
      hit = true;
    }
  }

  if (hit)
  {
    queue_free();
  }
}
```

The problem is, the `cast_to` always returns a pointer, even if two projectiles hit each other. That subsequently causes crash when trying to call `receiveDamage` on something that is not `ShootableObject`.

I can avoid the issue by doing this, but that's just plain stupid:

```
        if (body->get_class() != "ShootableObject")
        {
          return;
        }
```

Why is this happening? I tried to enable RTTI in my build in case there was a problem with that (shouldn't be) and that did not help. Is there something wrong with those class definitions?

Comment: Two things I would test, but which will not answer the question: what if you use a dynamic_cast instead of obejct::cast_to (it appears it is what godot's code is doing under the hood), and what if you cast the o to shootable instead of casting body to shootable?

Comment: What comes to mind is to use `is_instance_valid`. However I didn't find examples using that, and for what I'v seen I believe that what you are doing should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that was still occurring in Godot 4.0 (I tested it a few months ago) and is no longer occurring in Godot 4.1.